# switch case not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I Have Written This Code For Link Redirection But The Problem With The Code It  Triggered Only First Case It Omits Other Cases In The Switch Statement

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function () {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var string = links[i].href; //href value
        var str = string;
        var spl = string.split("/");
        switch (spl[2]) {

            case 'www.google.com':
                var str1 = "http://yahoo.com";
                links[i].target = "_blank";
                var m = links[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
                    window.open(str1)
                }, false);
                return (m);
                break;

            case 'www.ebay.com':
                var str1 = "http://yahoo.com";
                links[i].target = "_blank";
                var m = links[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
                    window.open(str1)
                }, false);
                return (m);
                break;

            default:
                links[i].href = string;
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">www.google.com</a></br>
<a href="http://www.ebay.com/">www.ebay.com</a></br>
```

Comment: Your code is duplicated between the first two `case`s, did you mean to do that?

Comment: it is working for google but it not working for ebay link redirection

Comment: Why do you have `return` statements in there? They will exit the `onload` function handler, so of course it only visits the first anchor element in the loop

Comment: For many of the questions asked on this site, I have to wonder if developers have access to common Javascript debugging tools, or if they're just editting and refreshing...Try pressing F12 in Chrome or Internet Explorer 9+ to get some very useful code-debugging tools.

Comment: Can Anyone Help Me To Write This Code For Internet Explorer...Just Because i am New 2 java-script n do not know much about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove return(m) from above code. It should work fine. It's return after first call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `return(m);` here, it returns from there and do not execute the rest of the code. you can test it by putting `alert("Hi");` after the return statement. This `alert` should not work for your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function () {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var string = links[i].href; //href value
        var str = string;
        var spl = string.split("/");
        switch (spl[2]) {

            case 'www.google.com':
                var str1 = "http://yahoo.com";
                links[i].target = "_blank";
                var m = links[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
                    window.open(str1)
                }, false);
                break;

            case 'www.ebay.com':
                var str1 = "http://yahoo.com";
                links[i].target = "_blank";
                var m = links[i].addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
                    window.open(str1)
                }, false);
                break;

            default:
                links[i].href = string;
        }

    }
}
</script>
```